# Disabled mac os SIP but still can't delete default apps

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm using mac os 11.2.1 Big Sur. My question concerns the Terminal utility.

I've disabled System Integrity Protection and confirmed it is off by typing:

csrutil

Terminal then returns "disabled," so SIP is definitely off. I've tried to delete various apps, for example, as follows:

sudo rm -rf FaceTime.app/

sudo rm -rf TV.app/

sudo rm -rf Mail.app/

However, nothing seems to happen. The apps are still in my Applications folder and launch normally. If I try to delete them manually, I get a beep and the deletion is rejected just as if SIP were still enabled. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions about programming, not general computer usage. Ask Different is a more appropriate forum, and this has already been covered there. See ["Catalina not allowing to change read/write permissions despite having SIP disabled"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375603/catalina-not-allowing-to-change-read-write-permissions-despite-having-sip-disabl) and ["Can I mount the root (system) filesystem as writable in Big Sur?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/395508/can-i-mount-the-root-system-filesystem-as-writable-in-big-sur)

Answer (score 0):

> You can get csrutil status by typing into the terminal:
>
> ```
> csrutil status
> ```
>
> It should return
>
> > System Integrity Protection status: enabled.
>
> or
>
> > System Integrity Protection status: disabled.
>
> Depending on its status.

You can't disable it by simply typing
`csrutil disable` into your terminal window.

The only way to disable it is through Recovery OS.

To get to the Recovery OS, you need to restart your machine and hold `⌘` + `R`,
navigate to the top menu bar, click on Utilities, Terminal.

[Recovery OS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJGGv.jpg)

Once you open the terminal inside Recovery OS you should be able to disable csrutil by typing

`csrutil disable`

Proceed to reboot the machine and log in back to your account.

Now you should be able to navigate to your /Applications folder and delete the native applications you don't want.

Answer (score -1):

I’ve disabled SIP through Recovery mode and it is definitely disabled, as terminal has confirmed so after my command. However, I’m still unable to delete default apps like Chess, Mail, etc.

I’m running Big Sur